# lookup tables in C++ 11 with multithreading

Tags: multithreading, c++11, thread-local

I have 2 similar situations in a multithreaded C++11 software :

- an array that I'm using as a lookup table inside a method declaration
- an array that I'm using as a lookup table declared outside a method and that is being used by different and several methods by reference or with pointers.

now if we forget for a minute about this LUTs and we just consider C++11 and a multithreaded approach for a generic method, the most appropriate qualifier for this methods in terms of storage duration is probably [`thread_local`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration).

This way if i feed a method `foo()` that is `thread_local` to 3 threads I basically end up having 3 instances of `foo()` for each thread, this move "solves" the problem with `foo()` being shared and accessed between 3 different threads, avoiding cache missings, but I basically have 3 possible different behaviours for my foo(), for example if I have the same PRNG implemented in foo() and i provide a seed that is time-dependant with a really good and high resolution, I probably will get 3 different results with each thread and a real mess in terms of consistency.

But let's say that I'm fine with how `thread_local` works, how I can write down the fact that I need to keep a LUT always ready and cached for my methods ?

I read something about a relaxed or less relaxed memory model, but in C++11 I have never seen a keyword or a practical application that can inject the caching of an array/LUT .

I'm on x86 or ARM.

I probably need something that is the opposite thing of `volatile` basically.

Comment: the easies thing would be not to share, of course. Are they big? If you need to share, TBB has a couple of implementations. There are quite a number of [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/820526/c-thread-safe-map) related if you google "concurrent hash table c++" :). If you work with VS, you have [concurrent_unordered_map](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh750089.aspx) at your disposal

Comment: @DmitryLedentsov thanks for that hint but it's probably not for me, I would like to write this in plain C++11 for portability and a better investment, also I would like to learn how to do this on my own, and yes, my LUTs can be big, imagine a LUT containing a big palette of colours or a similar set of values. My problem it's not about making this array a concurrent data structure, but how to make it cached.

Comment: I see. The nature of your question is not about the functionality itself. I'd go for the standard library first: [concurrent_unordered_map](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3425.html) at first, and start building my own only if I really need it. So, maybe, reconsidering the architecture will alleviate the need for a special concurrent lookup table

Comment: `thread_local` can only be applied to variables or static data members -- it makes no sense to talk about "a method that is `thread_local`"

Answer (score 3):

If the LUTs are read-only, so that you can share them without locks, you should just use one of them (i.e. declare them `static`).

Threads do not have their own caches. But even if they did (cores typically have their own L1 cache, and you might be able to lock a thread to a core), there would be no problem for two different threads to cache different parts of the same memory structure.

"Thread-local storage" does not mean that the memory is somehow physically tied to the thread. Rather, it's a way to let the same name refer to a different object in each thread. In no way does it restrict the ability of any thread to access the object, if given its address.

Comment: so in C++ I can make something `volatile` but I can't explicitly cache values ? In the end you are suggesting to modify the storage duration with `static` or `const` ( since `const` in this case generate the same effect ) and use this LUT with pointers or references ?

Comment: @user2485710: `volatile` doesn't "make something volatile". The something is either volatile or not; you have to know that. (For example, a hardware register is volatile.) `volatile` tells the compiler that it is volatile. Similarly, storage duration is just  about the way the compiler produces code; it's not something intrinsic to the storage.

Comment: @user2485710: And no, you cannot explicitly cache values, and even if you could, you don't need the values to be in a particular location in memory to do it.

Comment: yes, but you are supposed to use `volatile` when you have a business logic in your program that works with a "disposable" value or set of values in mind, for example if you know that this values are changing you inform the compiler that this values don't need a long life, I'm not sure about how the internals works regarding the memory model but I think that `volatile` can be part, if you want to implement it, of a more relaxed memory model. My point is I don't need to relax nothing, I have something that I know that I'll need in my constructs in multiple threads.

Comment: So in your opinion the best options are `static` or `const` ?

Comment: @user2485710: where did you get that explanation of `volatile` from? It's definitely not correct. `volatile` specifies that the value of the storage may change without notice, and that both writing and reading the variable may have arbitrary side-effects. Consequently, the compiler is not allowed to perform optimizations on `volatiles`, such as optimizing away a reference which is not otherwise used. It has nothing whatsoever to do with lifespan.

Answer (score 1):

The CPU cache is not programmable. It uses its own internal logic to determine which memory regions to cache. Typically it will cache the memory that either has just been accessed by the CPU, or its prediction logic determines will shortly be accessed by the CPU. In a multiprocessor system, each CPU may have its own cache, or different CPUs may share a cache. If there are multiple caches, a memory region may be cached in more than one simultaneously.

If all threads must see the same values in the look-up tables, then a single table would be best. This could be achieved with a variable with `static` storage duration. If the data can be modified then you would probably also need a `std::mutex` to protect accesses to the table and avoid data races. Read-only data can be shared without additional synchronization; in this case it is best to declare it `const` to make the read-only nature explicit and avoid accidental modifications.

```
void foo(){
     static const int lut[]={...};
}
```

You use `thread_local` where each thread must have its own copy of the data, usually because each copy will be modified independently. For example, you may choose to use `thread_local` for your random-number generator, so that each thread has its own RNG which is independent of the other threads, and does not require synchronization.

```
void bar(){
    thread_local RandomNumberGenerator rng; // one per thread
    auto val=rng.nextRandomNumber(); // use the instance for the current thread
}
```