# How to create thread safe cache of shared_ptr

Tags: c++, multithreading, shared-ptr

I have a code that reads a lot of files. Some files can be cached. Consumer receives `shared_ptr` when asks for a file. Other consumers can ask for this file and get it from the cache if file is still in memory. If file is not in memory, it will be loaded and put in to the cache.

Simplified code:

```
struct File
{
    File(std::string);
    bool AllowCache() const;
};

typedef std::shared_ptr<File> SharedPtr;
typedef std::weak_ptr<File> WeakPtr;
std::map<std::string, WeakPtr> Cache;

SharedPtr GetFile(std::wstring Name)
{
    auto Found = Cache.find(Name);
    if (Found != Cache.end())
        if (auto Exist = Found->second.lock())
            return Exist;

    auto New = boost::make_shared<File>(Name);
    if (New->AllowCache())
        Cache[Name] = New;
    return New;
}
```

My question is: how to make this code thead safe? Even if I protect content of `GetFile()` by a mutex, it still can return non-null pointer from `weak_ptr::lock()` while other thread is running destructor of pointed `File` object.

I see some solutions, like:

1. Store `shared_ptr`s in the cache and run a separate thread that will
   continuously remove `shared_ptr`-s with `use_count()==1` (let's call it `Cleanup()`).
2. Store `shared_ptr`s in the cache and require consumers to use special wrapper of `shared_ptr<File>`. This wrapper will have `shared_ptr<File>` as a member and will `reset()` it at destructor and then call `Cleanup()`.

1st solution is a bit ofoverkill. 2nd solution require to refactor all the code in my project. Both solutions are bad for me. Is any other way to make it thead safe?

Comment: As a stylistic sidenote: Please reconsider the use of Capital Letters for variable- and function names. It makes variables and functions look like Types / Declarations at the first glance, which makes reading the code much more difficult (at least for me). Also naming *anything* in C++ `New` is rather... bold (I spent 30s thinking "new? new what? are you missing the type for the pointer allocation?" before I realized `New` was a variable...)

Comment: Why don't you just use shared memory-mapping of the files and not worry about all this yourself?

Comment: As you noted you can make your cache thread safe with a simple mutex. The real question is how to make accessing the shared objects you obtain from the cache thread safe? That's a problem independant of the cache itself.

Comment: *"Even if I protect content of GetFile() by a mutex, it still can return non-null pointer from weak_ptr::lock() while other thread is running destructor of pointed File object."* - are you sure about that? I would think the `std::shared_ptr` would prevent `std::weak_ptr` access before destroying its target.

Comment: @CharonX this looked like Unreal Engine style to me at first, they have Capital variable naming ... but in usual C++ code this is slightly confusing

Comment: @Galik I'm not sure. May be I'm not right. I'll do a test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the scenario you've described, A `lock()` of a `WeakPtr` will fail (i.e. return a dummy `shared_ptr`) if another thread is running a destructor of the File object. That's the logic of shared and weak pointers. So - your current solution should be thread safe in this respect; but - it may be non-thread-safe as you add or remove elemnrs. Read about that, say, in this question: [C++ Thread-Safe Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820526/c-thread-safe-map) .

Comment: I wrote a test (see bellow). It prove you're right. `weak_ptr` does not return pointer to a dead object.

Answer (score 1):

I expected the following code will fail. But it's not. It seems like `weak_ptr::lock()` will not return pointer to an object that is in destruction process. And if so, it is a simpliest solution to just add a mutex and don't worry about returning dead objects by `weak_ptr::lock()`.

```
char const *TestPath = "file.xml";

void Log(char const *Message, std::string const &Name, void const *File)
{
    std::cout << Message
        << ": " << Name
        << " at memory=" << File
        << ", thread=" << std::this_thread::get_id()
        << std::endl;
}

void Sleep(int Seconds)
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(Seconds));
}

struct File
{
    File(std::string Name) : Name(Name)
    {
        Log("created", Name, this);
    }

    ~File()
    {
        Log("destroying", Name, this);
        Sleep(5);
        Log("destroyed", Name, this);
    }

    std::string Name;
};

std::map<std::string, std::weak_ptr<File>> Cache;
std::mutex Mutex;

std::shared_ptr<File> GetFile(std::string Name)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> Lock(Mutex); // locking is added
    auto Found = Cache.find(Name);
    if (Found != Cache.end())
        if (auto Exist = Found->second.lock())
        {
            Log("found in cache", Name, Exist.get());
            return Exist;
        }

    auto New = std::make_shared<File>(Name);
    Cache[Name] = New;
    return New;
}

void Thread2()
{
    auto File = GetFile(TestPath);
    //Sleep(3); // uncomment to share file with main thead
}

int main()
{
    std::thread thread(&Thread2);
    Sleep(1);
    auto File = GetFile(TestPath);
    thread.join();
    return 0;
}
```

My expectation:

```
thread2: created
thread2: destroying
thread1: found in cache <--- fail. dead object :(
thread2: destroyed
```

VS2017 results:

```
thread2: created
thread2: destroying
thread1: created <--- old object is not re-used! great ;)
thread2: destroyed
```